# How to to display validated form and table in same page ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I am trying to display both: Validated form and a database table on the same page. Code is below:

**Create Controller**

```
private object charity;

  // GET: Charities/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        return View(charity);  //Display 5 recent records from table 
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,DisplayName,Date,Amount,TaxBonus,Comment")] Charity charity)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Donations.Add(charity);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("AdditionalInfo");
        }
        return View(charity);
    }


    public ActionResult ChildList()
    {

        return View(db.Donations.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(5).ToList());
    }
```

**Create View**

```
 @model CharitySite.Models.Charity
@{
            ViewBag.Title = "Create";

     }

        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Donate-Style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

          <div>  @Html.Partial("_Form", Model);</div>

          <div> @Html.Action("ChildList");</div>

            <div class="donatebtn">
                @Html.ActionLink("Donate", "Additionalinfo")
            </div>

        @section Scripts {
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
            }
```

**Model**

```
public class Charity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Range(2, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value must be greater than 2")]
    public Double Amount { get; set; }
    public Double TaxBonus { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }
}

public class CharityDBContext : DbContext //controls information in database 
{
    public DbSet<Charity> Donations { get; set; } //creates a donation database



}
```

**Current Error Message**

```
 An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
    Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'
```

UPDATE-- 
I have created a method which returns the table list and used the HTML.ACTION list to display on the View. The above error is displayed.

Comment: You need to add the `[HttpPost]` attribute to the 2nd method. However that will only solve that error, and you will start to get different errors.

Comment: You `Create` method needs to return a `Charity` object (not a collection) and the `Create.cshtml` view needs to be `@model Charity` and be the form Then you need a separate controller method that returns the collection and display it in the view with `@Html.Action()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for answering, would you say its possible for me to just create a form in the the "Create.cshtml" and add the user information into the database from that created form?

Comment: Yes of course. Your `Create()` GET method should return a view that displays a form for a new `Charity` object. If in that view you also want to display a list of recent records, then use `@Html.Action()` to call a `ChildActionOnly` method that returns a partial view of those records.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ohh ok, I am trying your first approach right now, I have created a new method in the controller which returns the list and now I have to use the @Html.Action() but im unsure on how to utilize this in the Create.cshtml should I just call the Action name?

Comment: If you method is (say) `FetchRecent()` which returns a partial view for the recent items, then its `@Html.Action("FetchRecent")` (or `@{ Html.RenderAction("FetchRecent"); }`)

Comment: HI, I updated the question, is there anything I should ammend?

Comment: Have you created a `ChildList.cshtml` view that has `@model IEnumerable<Charity>` to display the items? (and you form should really be in the `Create.cshtml` view rather than using `@Html.Partial("_Form", Model);`)

Comment: Also (not related but) remove `private object charity;` and in the GET method use `return View(new Charity());`

Comment: Sorry I dont mean to sound stupid but where did you find the GET method? and if I remove the private object the red squigly line appears in the "Create" method underneath the parameter "charity"

Comment: The GET method is your first one - i.e. `public ActionResult Create()`. And you did not read my previous comment - its `return View(new Charity());`

Comment: IT WORKED!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

You need an httpPost above your second Create(...) method

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,DisplayName,Date,Amount,TaxBonus,Comment")] Charity charity)
{
..
}
```